# Advanced forum how to change the html without modifying the core

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to change the html for the topics list in Advanced forum module. I use a custom style. I foond that the file which displays the html is

> sites\all\modules\advanced_forum\styles\mystyle\advanced-forum.naked.topic-list-view.tpl.php

If I edit this file the changes are displayed. But I don't want to modify core files in order to be able to upgrade. So I tried to copy this file to my custom style's folder. But the changes are not displayed. Is it possible to change the html without modifying the naked style and if yes how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question was asked months ago, but I ran into a similar situation when trying to override an advanced_forum template.

The solution was to copy the file into your theme templates folder, and rename it removing the advanced_forums style name.

In the example of your case, you would copy the file:

*sites\all\modules\advanced_forum\styles\mystyle\advanced-forum.naked.topic-list-view.tpl.php*

to:

*sites\all\theme\mythemename\templates\advanced-forum-topic-list-view.tpl.php*

Note the name change, and that "mythemename" should be whatever your custom theme is. You may also need to copy the file advanced-forum-forums.tpl.php into your theme directory

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find the correct file name for your custom template files is to use the [Theme Developer moduel](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It allows you to point and click on anything in the browser and it tells you which part of the theme framwork rendered it and what options you have to override it.

Please note: You have to clear the theme registery after you added new templates, otherwise they are not shown.